# Changing default color of text

Tags: python, text, colors, kivy, kivy-language

In order to change the default color of all text in my app to black, I tried setting the [`color`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.color) property inside `<Label>` to `0,0,0,1`.

> color:
>
> Text color, in the format (r, g, b, a).
>   color is a ListProperty and defaults to [1, 1, 1, 1].

This however makes the text black regardless of any markup color used. For example the code at the bottom of the post creates 3 buttons with black text when `color: 0,0,0,1`:

[image]

and the expected white, red, green text color when `color: 1,1,1,1`:

[image]

I am assuming that `color` is applied after the markup coloring, causing the problem described above.

**Question:**
What is the correct way to change the default color of text?

Kivy version: 1.9.0

---

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


kv = """



<Label>:
    markup: True
    color: 0,0,0,1  # This defaults to 1,1,1,1 when not used

<MyWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'    
    Button:
        text: 'No markup text'
    Button:
        text: '[color=FF0000]Red markup[/color]'
    Button:
        text: '[color=7FFF00]Green markup[/color]'
"""    

Builder.load_string(kv)    

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyButtonsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyButtonsApp().run()
```

Comment: With your code, when base label color is `0,0,0,1`, the each consecutive label colors are black, red, green - correct. Which kivy version do you use and is it pygame or sdl2?

Comment: @jligeza The code above causes the same black-black-black text as in my screenshots, both in windows and ubuntu. I run this in pycharm; not using pygame. Don't know what sdl2 is, but I guess I am not using it. My kivy version is `1.9.0`. Do you mean that when you copy-paste the exact same code you don't get black-black-black?

Comment: Yes, on my machine everything works fine. I use kivy 1.9.2 dev with sdl2 graphics dependencies (it's not an IDE). Check installation manual for details.

Comment: @Fermiparadox It's recommended to use at least the latest stable version if not master instead. Bugs, at least of the framework itself seem to be fixed pretty fast for one to stay on single version for a long time.